# video system didn't initialize pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have some issue with quit the pygame

when I am trying to close the window, it tells me Video System didn't initialized
I don't know how to pack an image here, sorry. Error happens in line marked“!!!!!”

here is my code

```
    # PreTitleScreen

# cited from http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/
# f.php?file=sprite_collect_blocks.py
# the framework of this file are mostly cited from the above address


import pygame, configure, instructions, game

# constant 
PTS_WIDTH = 1024 # pre screen width
PTS_HEIGHT = 768 # pre Screen height

class TitleScreen():
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = configure.Configure()
        done = False
        pygame.init()
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        while not done:
            self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode([PTS_WIDTH,PTS_HEIGHT])
            pygame.display.set_caption("Bomberman")

            # import background image
            bgImagePath = self.c.IMAGE_PATH + "titleScreen.png"
            bgImage = pygame.image.load(bgImagePath).convert()
            bgImage = pygame.transform.scale(bgImage,(PTS_WIDTH,PTS_HEIGHT))
            self.screen.blit(bgImage,[0,0])

            pygame.mixer.music.load(self.c.AUDIO_PATH + "title.mid")
            pygame.mixer.music.play()

            # pygame.display.flip()
            notValidOp = False
            # under valid control mode
            while not notValidOp:
                print("enter the inner loop")
                # get mouse position 
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                 # testCode
                for event in pygame.event.get(): 
                  # deal with the exit
                    print('event.type', event.type)
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        print("quit")
                        notValidOp = not notValidOp
                        done = not done

                    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        print("get from general",pos)
                        if self.inBoundary(pos[0],pos[1],25, 500, 250, 550):
                            self.playGame("S")

                        elif self.inBoundary(pos[0],pos[1],25, 550, 250, 600):
                            self.playGame("M")

                        elif self.inBoundary(pos[0],pos[1],25, 600, 250, 650):
                            self.instructions()

                        elif self.inBoundary(pos[0],pos[1],25, 650, 250, 700):
                            print("high Score")
                            print("get from score",pos)

                        elif self.inBoundary(pos[0],pos[1],40, 700, 250, 750):
                            print("exit")
                            done = not done
                            notValidOp = not notValidOp

                # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
                pygame.display.flip()  # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

                # Limit to 60 frames per second
                clock.tick(self.c.FPS)


    def inBoundary(self,x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2):
        if ((x1 <= x0 <= x2) and (y1 <= y0 <= y2)):
            return True
        return False

    def instructions(self):
        instructions.Instructions()

    def playGame(self,mode):
        game.Game(mode)

# pygame.init()
# test Code below
TitleScreen()
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the right problem, but I'm pretty sure you have to quit the game (in your `if event.type == QUIT:` section) like so:

```
if event.type == QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Also, if you didn't `import pygame.locals as *` then you may have to use `pygame.locals.QUIT` instead of `QUIT`.

Comment: See comments above. it is one of the big differences between python 3 and python 2 version

Comment: Hey, cool. However, I believe you still have to call `sys.exit()`.
Plus, look at Sloth's answer.

Comment: HI, I have solve the problem. Actually, really no need it any more. I know we have to use .exit() in python 2, but no longer in python 3 version of Pygame. just set the done to not done, it's okay. It's like garbage collection system, you can explicitly exit it but not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you call `pygame.quit()` and then call  `pygame.display.flip()` afterwards.

You didn't show your complete code, but make sure that you don't call `pygame.display.flip()` after calling `pygame.quit()`.

Comment: actually, according to the document, we don't need to call pygame.quit() in python3 version, so I just don't. I don't know where is the problem